# laptop running Windows 7 started losing connection constantly 

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, 64-bit

So I got new laptop 64 bit with Windows 7 that I use wireless for internet.

For the first 3 or 4 months, high speed internet with no issues. End of January I started losing my connection. I can go to the router and reset and I get it back for maybe a 1/2 hour but it is slow and then I lose connection again.

My husband's iPod can connect and has high speed wireless anywhere in the house but my laptop continues to lose connection. I am not sure if I had a Windows Update that screwed everything up but it really annoying. Moreover we have reset our router and my problem still persists yet the iPod works.

Anyone have this issue and have a solution.

Comment: One thing you might look at is the "bloated" management software that comes with pre-installed OS Laptops.  Especially, in Wireless Management software I've seen a major reduction in connection speed, and availability.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a bad automatic driver update - Try going to computer management and looking at the wireless device and then possibly roll back the driver.

Alternatively, if no driver updates have been done, it could simply be interference (if it is a multi channel router) or degradation/damage to the wireless card (or aerial) itself.