# Windows 7 constantly loses and regains Internet connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, internet, internet-connection

I have a nettop with Windows 7 Pro on board, connected directly to a simple, four port router with ADSL modem on board, provided by my ISP.

After starting up or restarting nettop, it works fine. Since it has no keyboard nor LCD, I use TeamViewer to access it. I can work remotely without any problems for *some* period. Then, after few minutes, hours or days it starts to constantly loose and regain Internet connection. When, I'm on another machine with active TeamViewer, I can see messages saying, that my nettop has logged in, approximately one per 30-60 seconds (five times during writing this). In this state, nettop is completely not accessible and the only solution is to restart it.

This nettop is the only device connected  to this router (and the only in my 20 years of home-based networking), that has such strange problems.

I was told, that this somethimes happens on DHCP, however, that's not an issue in my case -- it has fixed values set for IP address, network mask and default gate as good as for both DNSes and it has reserved its IP on router pre-reservation pool (just like all other devices in my network).

Computer is connected through cable, so neither [this](https://superuser.com/q/674906/156554) nor [that](https://superuser.com/q/264526/156554) questions appeals, as both deal with wireless connection.

There are seven other devices using the same router/ADSL modem (through another router) and none of them have such problems, so networking devices should be fine. There was another device connected directly to ADSL modem, using the same cable and it was also dealing without problems. I think, this narrows potential causes to nettop itself.

Can anyone shed any light, what can be causing this problem? Or what to look for?

**Edit**: *This case has nothing to do with TeamViewer. I had that computer previously connected to a regular monitor and keyboard and I could observe, that it actually constantly looses and regains internet connection, even when TeamViewer was not yet installed there.*

Comment: It could be that you're hitting some sort of idle session timeout on TeamViewer. It's also possible that brief "hiccups" on your internet connection causes the session to cut off, whilst still appearing to maintain TeamViewer's online status.

Comment: @happy_soil This case has nothing to do with TeamViewer. I had that computer previously connected to a regular monitor and keyboard and I could observe, that it actually constantly looses and regains internet connection, even when TeamViewer was not yet installed there.